# simplify if statement in python 3.6

Tags: python, if-statement, simplify

I have the following code which is working fine and giving me the expected result, but i know there is a way to simplify it and i don't whats the best to way make to following code can be 3/4 lines instead of 20 odd or so. Python experts need your advice how i can ease the following code.

```
for ele in hng_row:
    if not ele.isdigit():
        if not ele.isalpha():
            if not ele.isalnum():
                if ele.endswith('.00'):
                    get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
                    ele = ele[:-1]
                    hng_row[get_index] = ele
                if ele.startswith('0.') and ele.endswith('0') and ele != '0.0':
                    get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
                    ele = ele[:-1]
                    hng_row[get_index] = ele
                if (ele[-2] != '0' ) and (ele[-2] != '.') and (ele[-1] == '0'):
                    get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
                    ele = ele[:-1]
                    hng_row[get_index] = ele
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what the code does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be post in the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the actual input and expected output? it may be easier to think on another approach than attempting to fix this one.

Comment: If your code is working, this question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh thanks i was not aware of the codereview thing. Will delete this question and post it there

Comment: You need to be clear about what you are trying to do, like including inputs and expected outputs, code review won't necessarily help without that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be simplified (or, well, lets say "shortened") further. First, note that checking `not isdigit`, `not isalpha` and `not isalnum` is redundant, you just have to check `not isalnum`. Second, you could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for checking the format of the number, combining your three conditions with `|`. Also, you can `enumerate` the items instead of getting the `index`.

```
for index, ele in enumerate(hng_row):
    if not ele.isalnum() and re.match(r"^.*\.00|0\..+0|.*[^0.]0$", ele):
        hng_row[index] = ele[:-1]
```

Here, the regex is `^.*\.00|0\..+0|.*[^0.]0$`. `^` marks the start of the string, `$` the end, and `|` a disjunction, i.e. the string has to match `.*\.00` (something followed by `.00`) or `0\..+0` (`0.`, then something, then `0`) or `.*[^0.]0` (something followed by neither `0` nor `.`, then `0`).

You could also replace the loop with a list comprehension:

```
>>> hng_row =  ['1531402200', 'primary', '2', '2100.00', '1.03', '1.05', '1.01', '2', '151'] 
>>> p = r"^.*\.00|0\..+0|.*[^0.]0$"
>>> [ele[:-1] if re.match(p, ele) else ele for ele in lst]
['1531402200', 'primary', '2', '2100.0', '1.03', '1.05', '1.01', '2', '151']
```

Comment: getting the following error -  AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'matches'

Comment: @PrateekGupta Whoops, it should be `re.match` (I did not really test this, since you provided no test cases)

Comment: thanks i have corrected it  another thing i have the following list and the code does not goes on to change any value                ['1531402200', 'primary', '2', '2100.00', '1.03', '1.05', '1.01', '2', '151']

Comment: actually it should change value from 2100.00 to 2100.0

Comment: @PrateekGupta Strange, it works for me. See my update.

Comment: thanks a lot this worked fine and helped me learning  a lot about python.

Comment: '>>> hng_row = ['1531482300', 'primary', '16336480', '5947232', '59.10', '256', '195216', '733940', '4194300', '4194300', '0.00', '76032']
>>> p = r"^.*\.00|0\..+0|.*[^0.]0$"
>>> hng_row = [ele[:-1] if re.match(p, ele) else ele for ele in hng_row]
>>> hng_row
['1531482300', 'primary', '1633648', '5947232', '59.1', '256', '195216', '73394', '4194300', '4194300', '0.0', '76032']'

Comment: any idea why the elements value 16336480 is changed to 1633648 @tobias_k

Comment: @PrateekGupta It matches your third condition `(ele[-2] != '0' ) and (ele[-2] != '.') and (ele[-1] == '0')`, does it not? If that's not the desired behaviour, please describe _in words_ what you are trying to achieve. (My guess would be that you _actually_ want to strip trailing zeros after a decimal point unless they are the only decimal digit?)

Answer (score 2):

First step: combine conditions (+pylint)

```
for ele in hng_row:
    if not ele.isdigit() and not ele.isalpha() and not ele.isalnum():
        if ele.endswith('.00'):
            get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
            ele = ele[:-1]
            hng_row[get_index] = ele
        if ele.startswith('0.') and ele.endswith('0') and ele != '0.0':
            get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
            ele = ele[:-1]
            hng_row[get_index] = ele
        if (ele[-2] != '0') and (ele[-2] != '.') and (ele[-1] == '0'):
            get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
            ele = ele[:-1]
            hng_row[get_index] = ele
```

Second step: refactor if-blocks

```
for ele in hng_row:
    if not ele.isdigit() and not ele.isalpha() and not ele.isalnum():
        if (ele.endswith('.00')
                or ele.startswith('0.') and ele.endswith('0') and ele != '0.0'
                or (ele[-2] != '0') and (ele[-2] != '.') and (ele[-1] == '0')):
            get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
            ele = ele[:-1]
            hng_row[get_index] = ele
```

Comment: third: combine conditions again, fourth: extract condition as helper function to improve maintainability

Comment: Also, `isdigit`, `isalpha` and `isalnum` is redundant.

Comment: Can you please throw an example

Answer (score 0):

The first few if statements can go on one line.

```
  for ele in hng_row:
        if not ele.isdigit() and not ele.isalpha() and not ele.isalnum():
            if ele.endswith('.00'):
                get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
                ele = ele[:-1]
                hng_row[get_index] = ele
            if ele.startswith('0.') and ele.endswith('0') and ele != '0.0':
                get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
                ele = ele[:-1]
                hng_row[get_index] = ele
            if (ele[-2] != '0' ) and (ele[-2] != '.') and (ele[-1] == '0'):
                get_index = hng_row.index(ele)
                ele = ele[:-1]
                hng_row[get_index] = ele
```